# inserted row in CTE not available to join on in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

i have a table **foo**

```
                            Table "public.foo"
      Column       |            Type             |              Modifiers              
-------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 foo_id            | uuid                        | not null default uuid_generate_v1()
 col1              | uuid                        | 
 col2              | uuid                        | 
 col3              | uuid                        | not null
```

I have a view **goo_view**, which selects primarily from foo, but also joins another table

```
SELECT * from foo LEFT JOIN foo_helper USING (foo_id);
```

I have the following CTE query in which i am attempting to insert into table **foo** whilst returning the appropriate **goo_view** information

```
WITH ins AS (
    INSERT INTO foo (col1,col2, col3) VALUES (111,222,333) RETURNING foo_id
)                              
SELECT v.foo_id, v.col1, v.col2, v.fk1
FROM goo_view v 
JOIN ins 
USING (foo_id)
```

however the result is empty.

If i run the insert and select separately it works, is there something about the timing that causes this to fail?

what is the work around?

Comment: It appears to me that the view should not be seeing the rows that were inserted or updated before statement-begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using an insert in a CTE?

```
WITH ins AS (
    select 111 as col1, 222 as col2, 333 as col3
) 
. . .
```

Does your syntax really work?  I haven't seen it before.  Wow, I just learned something. This appears to be [Postgres syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).

My best guess is that the returning clause you are using is returning one foo_id . . . the one you just inserted.  This foo_id is probably not present in goo_view, so there is no match and an empty set.

And, what you are trying to do is explicity not allowed in the documentation:

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot "see" each others' effects
>   on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query . . .

So, you are not going to see the new row in the view.  To fix this, you would have to explicitly reference the CTE in the `from` clause, using the results returned by `returning`.

Comment: clearly something is wrong since i am getting an emtpy result, but it does not trigger a syntax error..  I am looking for a way to get better returning results from my insert statement.  I would like the returned type to include the fields in the view as well as the fields in the table itself

Comment: I use similar syntax to catch "fresh" sequences after insert, but I use them in a another table , eg insert them into a temporary "hub" table.

Answer (score 2):

Since the view selects from the table `foo` in its state as of the start of the SQL command, you'll have to rewrite to something like:

```sql
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO foo (col1,col2, col3) VALUES (111,222,333)
   RETURNING foo_id, col1, col2
   )
SELECT i.foo_id, i.col1, i.col2, h.fk1
FROM   ins i
LEFT   JOIN foo_helper h USING (foo_id);
```

This way you take the *newly inserted* values and join the secondary table to it.

Comment: thanks unfortunately i really wanted to be able to maintain my view instead of my statement here...

Comment: You *could* use a left join to invoke the new rows into the view as well ;-) Or a right join. (what they say about great minds ...)

Comment: @DavidChan: Then you have to split the operation into two SQL commands, preferably inside a single transaction. If the combination of known inserted values is unique, you can use those as `WHERE` conditions to the view. Or you can save the result from the `RETURNING` clause in a temporary table. Or you can write a plpgsql function encapsulating the whole operation into a single transaction automatically ...

Answer (score 2):

BTW: with respect to isolation level there is (should be) no difference between a CTE, a chained RETURNING, a subquery, or a plain join. If a "subsequent" sub query refers to actual table tuples (i.e does a select), it should "see" the rows as-of query begin.

In other cases a query with a self-join update lake below could not work:

```
SET search_PATH='tmp';

DROP TABLE ztable CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE ztable
    ( id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , payload varchar
    );
INSERT INTO ztable(id,payload) VALUES (1,'one' ), (2,'two' ), (3,'three')
      ,(4,'four' ), (5,'five' ), (6,'six' );
SELECT * FROM ztable;

    -- This can only work if 
    -- t2 is seen in its original form
    -- **before the update**
UPDATE ztable t1
SET payload=t2.payload
FROM ztable t2
WHERE t1.id  = 7-t2.id
    ;
SELECT * FROM ztable;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
 id | payload 
----+---------
  1 | one
  2 | two
  3 | three
  4 | four
  5 | five
  6 | six
(6 rows)

UPDATE 6
 id | payload 
----+---------
  6 | one
  5 | two
  4 | three
  3 | four
  2 | five
  1 | six
(6 rows)
```

The tuples returned by CTE's or "chained table expressions" yielded by RETURNING of course are virtual; they do not refer to actual tuples, but to freshly "synthesised" new entities.